# fadeOut() on scrollTop() == 0 doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got a little Icon on my page which should fade in when I am on the top of my page. When I scroll down a bit, it should fade out. But when i go back up again, it reappears. I thought that should work with this code:

```
 if ($(document).scrollTop() === 0){
    $('#down').fadeIn(200);
    console.log("Hi");
  }
  else{
    $('#down').fadeOut(200);
    console.log("Bye");
  }
```

but obviously it doesn't. Here's a little [codepen](http://codepen.io/tobiasglaus/pen/PWLJOm)

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/scroll/

Comment: You need an event listener, and you need to add jQuery to your codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZLPXjw Always, ALWAYS, check at least the browser console before opening a question.

Comment: If you guys took the time to look at his codepen, you'd see he is using the scroll even listener

Comment: You haven't included jQuery in your pen (go to the settings icon on the JS pane and select jQuery from the quick-add drop down). Once jQuery is there, it works. Next time, check the console for errors first. (ReferenceError: $ is not defined)

Comment: @Bill Yes, I do now :) I updated it after Armin solved my question!

Comment: I know that I forgot jQuery on the pen. I did this pen just to show you what I got on my webpage. I got jQuery on my webpage. Thanks everyone !

Comment: Ahhh, I see! My bad! Check the answer as correct if it helped!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add it inside `onscroll` functionality. For example:

```
 $(window).scroll(function(){

  });
```

or

```
$( "#down" ).scroll(function() {
});
```

Comment: Perfect! Totally forgot that.